# How can i fire command where MenuItem with child

Tags: wpf, command, menuitem

When click an MenuItem with child, not firing command.
Command are well binding.

MenuItem without children's command is operating normally.

```
<MenuItem Header = "TopMenu" Command = "{Binding TopCommand}"> <!-- Not firing -->
    <MenItem Header = "ChildMenu" Command = "{Binding ChildCommand}" /> <!-- Fire -->
</MeuItem>
```

So, I using the Interaction...not firing

```
<MenuItem Header = "TopMenu" Command = "{Binding TopCommand}"> <!-- Not firing -->
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command = "{Binding TopCommand}"/>
        </I:EventTrigger>
    <i:Interaction.Trigger>
    <MenItem Header = "ChildMenu" Command = "{Binding ChildCommand}" /> <!-- Fire -->
</MeuItem>
```

How can I use Command on MenuItem with child?

thanks you

Answer (score 1):

When you click in a MenuItem, first it checks if it has children elements, if it is true, it displays the children elements if it is false it runs the command.

However you can use Triggers:

```
     <Menu>
         <MenuItem Header="Father">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command = "{Binding FatherCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger> 
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <MenuItem Header="Child" Command="{Binding ChildCommand}"></MenuItem>
         </MenuItem>
     </Menu>
```

That code works for me.

Comment: Use the Interaction trigger method is already in my question.
But it does not work.

Comment: However your code has some errors   `</I:EventTrigger>`    `<i:Interaction.Trigger>`